# Google Drive Spreadsheet Formula to Check Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a `Google Drive` spreadsheet with two sheets.

`Sheet 1` has three columns: `name`, `date`, `type`

`Sheet 2` also has three columns: `name`, `date`, `proposed`

I want to write a script that will run when I edit either sheet and highlight `proposed` on `Sheet 2` (if conditions are met).

The script should take the name from `Sheet 2` and find all related records on `Sheet 1`.  Then from those records, find those that have a specific `type` (in this case "Last Date", and from those rows, return the `MAX()` date.  If that date matches the `proposed` column in `Sheet 2`, then highlight `proposed`.

I am already able to color `proposed` if `date` matches, but I need help getting the correct date into `date` based on the  mentioned criteria.

Is it better/possible to write a formula in `Sheet 2 date` to get the needed data from `Sheet 1`?  Or, do I need to write a script to populate the `proposed` column after a change to `Sheet 1`?

With either/both case(s), how do I do that?  None of my searches have helped me get there.

I have tried to write cell formulas like this: `=arrayformula(IF('Sheet 1'!C2:C500="Last Date",min(ROW('Sheet 1'!C2:C500)),""))` and many variations of that, but none have produced the results I need.

I could easily write this in `Excel`, but can't figure out the `Google Drive` equivalent.  Here is one way to do it in `Excel`:

`=MAX(IF(2name=1nameRage, IF(1typeRange = "Last Date",1dateRange)))`

Here is my function to check the name and call the related functions.

```
function onEdit(e){
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
   if(sheet.toString()=="Sheet 2"){
      dataCheck(e);
   }else if(sheet.toString()=="Sheet 1"){
      colorItems("Sheet 2","dataRange");
   }
} 
function dataCheck(e){
   var col = e.range.getColumn();
   if(col==2){
      var row = e.range.getRow();
      var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col);
      var bgc = cell.getBackground();
      var cProp = cell.getValue();
      var cLast = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1).getValue();
      if(cLast.toString()==cProp.toString() && cProp.toString()!=""){
          cell.setBackgroundRGB(190, 190, 190);
      }else if (bgc=="#bebebe"){
          cell.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
      }
   }
}
function colorItems(sheetName,nameRange){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var data = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = data.getNumRows();

    var pDates = ss.getRangeByName(nameRange);

    var pDateObject = getRowsData(sheet, pDates);

    for (var i = 0; i <= numRows; i++) {
        var cell = sheet.getRange(i+2, 2, 1, 1);
        var cLast = pDateObject[i].last;
        var cProp = pDateObject[i].proposed;
        if(!isCellEmpty(cProp)){
           if(cLast.toString() ==cProp.toString()){
              cell.setBackgroundRGB(190, 190, 190);
           }
        }else{
           cell.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, ironically, by copying my Excel formula:

```
=arrayformula(MAX(IF('Sheet 1'!C2:C500="Last Date",IF(D2='Sheet 1'!A2:A500,'Sheet 1'!B2:B500))))
```